# WordPress REST API response is empty in browser and script, but not in Postman

Tags: javascript, rest-api

I'm trying to do a super simple fetch to grab some user data for my WP site. This URL works 100% in Postman and I get everything I need. However, in the browser and script, the response is ALWAYS an empty array.

Here's my script:

```
fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOjIsIm5hbWUiOiJsemFrb29yIiwiaWF0IjoxNjYzMTA5MzU2LCJleHAiOjE4MjA3ODkzNTZ9.2l957IqslJBsvY9MrV5dT0ykod7kloFCc5qSxGeGlT0",
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            }
        })
        // Handle success
        .then(response => response.json()) // convert to json
        .then(json => console.log(json)) //print data to console
        .catch(err => console.log('Request Failed', err)); // Catch errors
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried almost everything I can think of. Postman gives me the proper JSON response every time.

The URL is this: /wp-json/wp/v2/users/
Raw:

```json
{"id":668,"name":"008LT","url":"","description":"","link":"author\/008lt\/","slug":"008lt","avatar_urls":{"24":"wp-content\/plugins\/buddyboss-platform\/bp-core\/images\/profile-avatar-buddyboss-50.png","48":"wp-content\/plugins\/buddyboss-platform\/bp-core\/images\/profile-avatar-buddyboss-50.png","96":"wp-content\/plugins\/buddyboss-platform\/bp-core\/images\/profile-avatar-buddyboss-50.png"},"meta":{"project_code":[null],"hours_approved":[],"hours_used":[]},"acf":{"password_was_reset":"yes","acad_coordinator":"Mariah G.","project_poc":"Someone else","student_admin":"Test 1","admin_contact":"Someone","project_id":"11104.0028.001","hd_project_id_status":"","primary_language":"lithuanian (lit)","secondary_language":"russian (rus)","approved_hours":30,"used_hours":15,"todays_appointments":"","scheduled_instructor":"","training_focus":"","jlu":"","let_status":"","cl150_status":"","iltp":"","pmo_account-type":"","hd_account_status":"","tutor_orientation":"","class_activity":"","next_test":"","test_date":"","class_recording":"","last_updated":null,"student_category":"dlt","student-iltp":""},"_links":{"self":[{"href":"wp-json\/wp\/v2\/users\/668"}],"collection":[{"href":"wp-json\/wp\/v2\/users"}],"courses":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"wp-json\/ldlms\/v2\/users\/668\/courses"}],"groups":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"wp-json\/ldlms\/v2\/users\/668\/groups"}],"course-progress":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"wp-json\/ldlms\/v2\/users\/668\/course-progress"}],"quiz_progress":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"wp-json\/ldlms\/v2\/users\/668\/quiz-progress"},{"embeddable":true,"href":"wp-json\/ldlms\/v2\/groups\/668\/quiz-progress"},{"embeddable":true,"href":"wp-json\/ldlms\/v2\/groups\/668\/quiz-progress"}]}}
```

Comment: you will need to invalidate those tokens now that you've shared them, it's not clear what the URL/endpoint is or the raw response before it's converted to JSON

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm still learning quite a few things. I've added the raw response and endpoint below my question

Comment: was that the raw response from postman or the raw response from the JS in the browser? You can see the raw response via the browser dev tools network panel, that's what you need to share ( and make sure it's labelled as such to avoid confusion )

Comment: That was Postman's response. The browser is empty every single time. Both the script and when I paste the URL I'm calling directly

Comment: Have you checked the Network panel though? I'm not interested in Postman, or the `console.log` output, I'm interested in the _raw_ network response that chrome/firefox receives _before_ it's handed to JS. If you're using JS to output the value then that value is tainted. Looking at the request itself in the network panel bypasses any mistakes or missing steps and shows you the raw unprocessed network request. Also keep in mind that you've still not expanded your code snippet to include what came before it. This could be a trivial mistake creating `url`.

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for that. I'm now receiving the error that I'm not allowed to list users. But you kind of sent me down a decent rabbit hole. The answer for me was setting the `X-WP-Nonce` with the `wpApiSettings.nonce` in the headers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for me was setting the X-WP-Nonce with the wpApiSettings.nonce in the headers.